# Insert missing UL tag to LIs

Tags: jquery, html

Because the menu is being generated dynamically using a CMS and the way the php is somehow coded, its missing the UL tag, so my question how can I insert/add/append the UL tag to enclose the LIs using JQuery.

This is the rendered code by the CMS

```
<h3 class="italic orange">Accounting Packages</h3>
<div class="sidebarmenu">
  <li><a href="#">What Is It</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
</div>
```

Thanks & Regards
Said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the jQuery `.wrapAll()` function:

```
$('.sidebarmenu').children().wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecgbnt7b/)